# Include selected parts of an external site

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I have gotten a question from a friend who has a website and a blog (Wordpress). They are on completely different domains. As it is now, each time she enters a new article on the blog, she manually has to update the "News"-section on her website. Now, she would like it to update automatically. So when she updates her blog, the newest article is also shown on the website.

Is it even possible to achieve this and can you advance even further, like letting say the three most recent articles display in the website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress has a buil-in RSS system. Use that blog RSS on your other site to automatically show them as news.

If you want to manually create it, [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds) is a good manual on how to start that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is called `web syndication`

Many blogging frameworks already offer syndication support out of the box, using RSS, Atom, or a comparable system.

All you need to do is get the CMS on her website to read the syndication of her blog and fetch the latest articles from it.